# JavaFX Scene Builder - set Rectangle resizable

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using Scene Builder with JavaFX. I'm trying to create a sidebar in my application with a difference background color.

I have a rectangle in my AnchorPane and I want the rectangle to always match the window height. So when I resize the window, the rectangle height should change. For some reason the `resizable` checkbox is disabled in the rectangle properties.

If this is not easily possible using Scene Builder, is there another component I can use for this purpose, other than rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use it like this. I hope your Problem will be solved.

[image]

Here you can see a Anchor Pane which includes the Border Pane. In the Top-Section i add a MenuBar, in the Left Section i add a VBOX and the Center includes a BarChart. The Footer is only a HBox with a Label inside.

This is the easiest way to get what you want i think!

This is the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="410.0" prefWidth="599.9998779296875" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <children>
        <BorderPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
          <bottom>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color:lightgrey;">
              <children>
                <Label text="This is a Footer Section" />
              </children>
            </HBox>
          </bottom>
          <center>
            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color:grey;">
              <children>
                <BarChart>
                  <xAxis>
                    <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                  </xAxis>
                  <yAxis>
                    <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                  </yAxis>
                </BarChart>
              </children>
            </VBox>
          </center>
          <left>
            <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="352.0" prefWidth="90.0" style="-fx-background-color:darkgrey;">
              <children>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="SidebarItem" />
              </children>
            </VBox>
          </left>
          <right>
            <VBox prefHeight="352.0" prefWidth="56.0" style="-fx-background-color:darkgrey;" />
          </right>
          <top>
            <MenuBar>
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
          </top>
        </BorderPane>
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Lukas Adler

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried messing with this but rectangle seems to work differently.

Comment: Ok, why is it important to use rectangle ? @john

Comment: I need to create a sidebar that looks different from the rest of the screen. Rectangle seems to be the only component whose backcolor you can change.

Comment: I working on a wizard like screen, and I'm trying to show the progress on the sidebar. (like this: http://media-cache-cd0.pinimg.com/236x/0d/1c/55/0d1c550e95b4087d08ff7454df5d9049.jpg)

Comment: You can change the Background-Color of each component! You have to use Cascading Style Sheets for that! Otherwise you can addStyles in your Java Code as well. You can create an component and add there a Style like that: **component.addStyle("-fx-background-color:green;");** < You also can change the color of components to a transparent style... I think it would be easier to use a VBOX instead of a Rectangle!! Otherwise i can not really understand your problem.

Comment: @john -> Every Background-Color is changeable in JavaFX !

Comment: Thank you very much. Going to try that.

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot. Small question: if I have a label with `fxid= lbl`, how can I access this from my controller class? I want to change its font type from bold to regular. (I already have a button click event working fine, I just dont know how to access a different component using an fxid.)

Comment: You can change the font by CSS also -> You have to add more or less something like this :.label {
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: Can you connect your Label to your Controller ? You have to add to your Controller Class a @FXML - Tag to a referenced Label.

Comment: I added an fid to the label via Scene Builder. I also linked the controller class. Can I just directly reference it in the code `@FXML myLabel.setText("foo")` or do I have to create a reference to the label first?